# smiley to image - optimized PHP code

Tags: php

is it a good code or it can be optimized  ?

```
 $tempmsg = str_replace("[:)]","<img src='img/smiley0.png' title='Smile' height='100' width='100'>",$tempmsg);
```

Comment: with OPTIMIZED i want to mean a FIGURE OUT IF THERE IS ANY ERROR IN MY CODE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1/ Can it be optimized?

It is pretty good, you're not using regular expressions (preg_replace) so no worries here.

### 2/ Is it a good code

To me it is not really readable. How about if you need to replace other smileys? It is not reusable. Here is a first step towards better readability, increased reusability, ... It might be a bit slower, but I tend to favor reusability over performance until I need to optimize.

```
function replace_smiley($text) {
  $replacements = array( 
     ":)" => "image1.jpg", 
     ":(" => "image2.jpg"
  );

  $out = $text;
  foreach ($replacements as $code => $image) {
    $html = '<img src="img/' . $image . ' alt="' . $code . '" height="100" width="100" />';
    $out = str_replace($code, $html, $out);
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Of course, depending on the requirements, there is always room for improvement.

Comment: Like adding `return $out` to the function? ;-)

Comment: Yep, that's a big improvement with respect to usability of the function :)

Answer (score 1):

Optimized how? It's hard to optimize things down past a single line of code. I'd suggest adding the smiley as ALT text though, for those who don't have image capability or if the images fail to transfer for some reason. But that's not "optimization". That's simply good design.

```
 $tempmsg = str_replace(blah blah blah .... alt=":)" ...);
```

Comment: And use single quotes instead of double quotes: faster and you get double quotes in your resulting HTML, which is nicer or mandatory if using XHTML

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would build it:

```
function replace_smiley($text){
    $replacements = array(
        ':)' => 'image1.jpg',
        ':(' => 'image2.jpg'
    );

    $search = array();
    $replace = array();

    foreach($replacements as $key => $val){
        $search[] = $key;
        $replace[] = '<img src="images/' . $val . '" alt="' . $key . '" />';
    }

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
}
```

It's efficient, easy to maintain and probably as optimized as it can be.